# Rails has_many :through, undefined method

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

having some trouble with a many to many relationship in rails. I have three modals:

1. Order
2. Item
3. Itemized

An order has many items through itemized and vice-versa.

Querying Item.find(1).orders works fine, but when I try Order.find(1).items It returns:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `items' for #<Order:0x007fcad3bb3258>
```

Here's my code:

Schema.rb

```
create_table "itemizeds", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "item_id",    limit: 4
  t.integer  "order_id",   limit: 4
  t.integer  "quantity",   limit: 4
  t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
end

create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title",      limit: 255
  t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
end

create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "customer_id", limit: 4
  t.integer  "store_id",    limit: 4
  t.integer  "order_id",    limit: 4
  t.datetime "created_at",                                    null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                                    null: false
  t.decimal  "price",                 precision: 8, scale: 2
  t.decimal  "discount",              precision: 8, scale: 2
end
```

Order.rb (model)

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :itemized
  has_many :items, :through => :itemized
end
```

Item.rb (model)

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :itemized
  has_many :orders, :through => :itemized
end
```

Itemized.rb (model)

```
class Itemized < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Not sure if maybe it's interfering, but there's also a store model, and a store has many orders.

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: What does `Order.find(1).itemized` return?

Comment: #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Itemized id: 1, item_id: 1, order_id: 1, quantity: 1, created_at: "2016-02-10 03:31:53", updated_at: "2016-02-10 03:31:53">, #<Itemized id: 2, item_id: 2, order_id: 1, quantity: 1, created_at: "2016-02-10 03:31:53", updated_at: "2016-02-10 03:31:53">]>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I look at many to many associations in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html I see

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

So I suppose it is a problem of pluralisation. Try `:through => :itemizeds` instead.